# Exchanging messages in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, postmessage

One way to get around same origin policy is to use an iframe to exchange messages/data by registering a message callback event listener on the app itself.

```
window.addEventListener("message", message_callback);
```

and the actual function that will receive messages posted by the iframe

```
function message_callback(msg)
{
       //do whatever with the data returned in the message that is posted by iframe
}
```

With this sort of setup, I can post messages to the iframe, have the iframe perform an ajax call, and on the success of the ajax call, post the results back to the application.

My question is, what is the best practice/ideal way to accomplish this in angular? That is, how should one go about posting messages/receiving messages from an iframe?

I was thinking about placing some sort of message callback function on the $rootScope, though I'm unsure if this is best practice and where exactly to go from here

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope) {
$rootScope.message_callback= function (msg) {
    // do some stuff
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

same domain policy can not be skipped by iframes, the only way an iframe can interact with a parents js is if the iframe comes from the same domain as the parent. so am asuming you are redirecting your iframe back to your app domain where you will excecute a JS function trying to do something in the parent scope(executing a function).

your function could have something like

```
angular.element($('*[ng-app]')).scope();
```

tha should grab the scope of your app $rootScope and then you can perform any operation permitted in that scope.

from there you can broadcast events, fire a service notification or perform scope specific task.

am using $('*[ng-app]') asuming you have jquery or zizzling.js to eprform css selection but you could use any method to get the DOM element you want to get the scope for.

Comment: can set `document.domain` in both and they are considered same origin, assuming you have access to both iframe and page to do it

Comment: correct but you still need to be under the same domain. document.domain will only allow you to change the domain to the shortest domain version to skip the same domain limitation on subdomains.

Comment: for what i've heard :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

you can't the only way you can do this is by creating a subdomain and point it to the ip address of the other domain, and call it in your iframe using this new subdomain,  same master domain. if you have happen to know where can i find  literature of a different method, please post it, i would like to learn more about it. thanks